How to map JSON object from SQL Server query to a C# class model field in ASP.NET Core
I'm trying to map a JSON column in my database table to my model, but I'm not sure how to do this.
Currently using SQL Server with Dapper and not Entity Framework Core
From other posts, I can see that there are examples of how to map individual properties in the JSON to a field, but I want to map the entire JSON object I get back from the SQL query to the model field.
JSON from the SQL Server query:
{
  "data": {
    "name": "Hello",
    "aliases": ["world", "hi"],
    "address": {
       "main": "123 street"
    {
  }
}

// DB Model

public class MyDBModel
{
  int Id {get; set;} 
  string MyJsonColumn {get; set;} = string.Empty;
}

//Client models to map the JSON
public class ClientModel 
{
  public Data data { get; set; } = null;
}

public class Data
{
  string name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
  string[] aliases { get; set; } = null;
  Address address { get; set; } = null;
}

public class Address
{
  string main { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

I want to map the above JSON to my model classes
**************** UPDATE *****************
When I try to map the model doing
var response = _sqlConnection.Query<MyDBModel>(sql);

return new ClientModel 
{
  Id = response.Id,
  data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ClientModel >(response.MyJsonColumn );
}

I get an error

Cannot implicitly convert type ClientModel to My.DB.Models.Namespace.Data

Why is it referring to the Data client model?

Hi @henhen, If you don't need a strongly-typed structure and just want to access the JSON data dynamically, you can use JObject.  Otherwise, you need create a model to map the json data.

You need Deserialize<Data>.

@tmaj ty, I had already figured it out

If you store json in a column in the database and you need to retrieve all of it then desalinizing in the code is a popular approach.
If you need to retrieve only some information you can use JSON_VALUE and then you may not need to have a complex type in MyJsonResponse.
If you need the whole object then you could use two types:
public class PersonDetailsDb
{
   ...other properties,

   public string MyJsonResponse { get; set; } = null;

}

public class PersonDetails
{
   ...other properties,

   public MySpecialType MyJsonResponse { get; set; } = null;
}


Then:
using System.Text.Json;

...

var fromDb = sqlConnection.Query<PersonDetailsDb>(sql);

return fromDb.Select(x => new PersonDetails(
    ...other fields,
    myJsonResponse: JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PersonDetails>(MyJsonResponse);
));


When you mentioned desalinizing, did you mean deserializing the json like here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/deserialization

I tried doing it this way, but I get an error about not being able to convert the response to the special type. Can you check the OP please? I've updated it with my details on my model
